# Excel Return another cell value if a match is found in an array of list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do you get the value for a Price Row in an excel having three rows below with a condition if a Name exist in list of all Names return the price as a result. So in case of X and Y since it exist in list of array for all names I want to get 5 and 6 for the result

```
 Name   All List of Names   Price 
 X         T                1
 Y         R                2
 Z         E                3
 A         Q                4
 B         X                5
 C         Y                6
```

Comment: A VLOOKUP()?  If that will not work than more explanation with your expected outcome would be helpful.

Comment: Hi @ScottCraner yeah vlookup but how would the formula be ? :) Help if you have any clue

Comment: Go watch the video at [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `VLOOKUP` formula--as mentioned in the comments above.

Insert two columns between the "Name" column and "All List of Names".

Then enter `=VLOOKUP(A2,$D$2:$E$7,2,FALSE)` in B2 and drag down as needed.
[image: vlookup]

[image: vlookup2]

This will return the corresponding value in the range that matches the respective "Name".